# OAuth login with Google Apps Engine endpoint stopped working

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth, google-oauth, signpost

I have a desktop Java application that communicates with a GAE server. The client application signs in to the server using OAuth 1.0 with signpost via the provided endpoints 
(appname.appengine.com/_ah/OAuthGetAccessToken and the like) with consumerkey and consumersecret set to "anonymous" and scope set to the GAE domain. The login process appears to be working fine:

1. Retrieve Request Token
2. Let the user visit the resulting authentication URL
3. Ask user for verification code
4. Retrieve Access Token

At this point, I have a seemingly valid token and token secret. If I use these to sign a request to the GAE server, I get an *OAuthRequestException* when identifying the user:

```
OAuthService oauthService = OAuthServiceFactory.getOAuthService();
try {
    user = oauthService.getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        ri.userName = user.getEmail();
    }
} catch (OAuthRequestException t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

**This used to work fine until this morning**. I am using a modified version of the [Chrome to Phone](https://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/source/browse/trunk/appengine/src/com/google/android/chrometophone/server/RequestInfo.java#78) GAE backend. I noticed that **Chrome to Phone is having the same issue**: I cannot login to the service anymore, so I don't believe this is an error on the client side. Logins don't show up in the *Google Connected Sites, Apps, and Services console*. Here is a link to the affected line in Chrome to Phone's GAE service: [Chrome2Phone affected source](https://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/source/browse/trunk/appengine/src/com/google/android/chrometophone/server/RequestInfo.java#78).

I already tried registering the application in the Google API console and provided comsumer key and secret, with the same result.

Comment: Here is the code I use for the signed request: `HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
request.setRequestMethod("POST");
request.setUseCaches(false);
request.setRequestProperty("X-Same-Domain", "true");
request.setRequestProperty("GData-Version", "3.0");
request.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.setDoOutput(true);
OAuthConsumer consumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer("anonymous","anonymous");
consumer.setTokenWithSecret(consumer.getToken(), consumer.getTokenSecret() );
consumer.sign(request);
request.connect();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't exactly an answer, but I'm seeing the same new behavior on a python app engine app using the built-in oauth provider libs (`google.appengine.api.oauth`). Existing saved tokens continue to work, but requesting a new token and then using it to call a protected service results in a `InvalidOAuthTokenError`. This is with unchanged consumer and provider code that worked flawlessly until last night (approximately midnight CST).

Comment: Thanks for leaving a comment. If this really affects more users and applications, we'll probably have to wait it out until Google notices and fixes this problem? Is there any way to report this bug?

Comment: I created an issue here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8785

Answer (score 4):

We made some back end changes to our authentication system which ended up not being compatible with App Engine code relying on the authentication system. It appears to be a rather straightforward issue and we are in progress with a fix. We don't have an exact timeline on resolution yet but expect it to be soon.

---

Update: the fix has been rolled out to production as of about 8pm PST. Thanks everyone your patience.